# Android map : compatible on all phones?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I need a kind of map explorer in my android app.
To use android MapActivity, I need to build with Google API, and not with standard Android API.

What does exactly mean ? Will my application only work on Google phone and not on others (Samsung) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's safe to assume that the Google API is included on almost every single Android device on the market today, Samsung, HTC, Sony Ericsson ect. So don't be afraid of using it. :)